# Invalid location of image in text

Tags: floats, positioning

I have following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[color=red,opacity=0.1,contents={}]{background}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\author{Marko Frelih \\ Company \\ \texttt{email}}
\title{Title}
\date{Ljubljana, Marec 2015}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Prvi zagon}
Pred prvim zagonom moramo na Raspberry Pi B+ priklopiti monitor ali televizijski sprejemnik preko HDMI kabla,
tipkovnico preko USB vrat ter kabel za internet preko ethernet vrat. Ko to storimo, pri\v{z}gemo Raspberry Pi B+
z vklopom napajalnika preko micro USB kabla v micro USB re\v{z}o in Rasbperry Pi B+ se pri\v{z}ge, aktivnost
nalaganja linux operacijskega sistema vidimo na ekranu/televizorju. Najprej se prika\v{z}e predstavitveno okno:
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{slike/image_rPiBPlusSplashScreen.png}
\caption{Rasperry Pi B+ predstavitveno okno}
\end{figure}
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

which produces result, described in [image: Situation Screenshot]. Obvisously, the inserted image is in wrong position, it should be placed in the centre (which is), but UNDER the text, not ABOVE It. What am I missing?

Comment: `figure` is a floating environment, that can move to avoid bad page breaks. See [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)
and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ok, but I my code wrong or what?

Comment: No, it's not wrong, you just didn't know how the `figure` environment works. You can try adding all the possible float position specifiers in the optional argument of the figure, i.e. `\begin{figure}[htbp]`. Read the second post I linked to above to fully learn what that means.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Can you advance comment into question so I can mark it answered?

Comment: No, I'd rather close as a duplicate, what I wrote above is the first suggestion in [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2282)